# Intellisense of generic function

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have this function:

```
export type ViewStyleProps = StyleProp<ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle> 

export interface ViewStyles {
    [key: string]: ViewStyleProps
}

export function toStyle<T extends ViewStyles>(obj: T): T  {
    return ESS.create(obj)
}
```

where the `ViewStyleProps` is a type alias of intersection of some other types.

Here, when I try to use `toStyle` function, intellisense does help for the keys of whatever returns from the function, but no help for the passed object.

For example;

```
const style = toStyle({
    anyKey: {
        // Here should show the keys of ViewStyleProps ONLY but nothing shown
    }
})

// But at this point, when you use the return value, it does show `anyKey` after point
style.{{ anyKey }}
```

Comment: What editor are you using? This works fine in the TypeScript Playground. By the way, `{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] }` is the same as just `T`.

Comment: @Tao Thank you, I have noticed it, I'm using VSCode.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with VSCode.  Also your definition of `ViewStyleProps` is quite possibly relevant here, but you haven't included it.

Comment: @jcalz I have updated it, that type was simply React-Native StyleProps combination

Comment: Sorry, [still can't reproduce](https://imgur.com/a/BoPo0).